# Encriptar y descencriptar un texto en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito encriptar y descencriptar información en PHP. El código que estoy usando es este.

```
$clave  = 'Soft20';
$method = 'aes-256-cbc';
$iv = base64_decode("C9fBxl1EWtYTL1/M8jfstw==");

 $encriptar = function ($valor) use ($method, $clave, $iv) {
     return openssl_encrypt ($valor, $method, $clave, false, $iv);
 };
 // $dato_encriptado = $encriptar("1");

 $desencriptar = function ($valor) use ($method, $clave, $iv) {
     $encrypted_data = base64_decode($valor);
     return openssl_decrypt($valor, $method, $clave, false, $iv);
 };
 // $dato_desencriptado = $desencriptar("sT3G+GIcEepQ3A5MGX48TQ==");

 /*
 Genera un valor para IV
 */
 $getIV = function () use ($method) {
     return base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method)));
 };
```

Me han dicho que este código es inseguro. Alguna vez me hablaron de AES, que es un modo de encriptar en PHP. ¿Me podrían ayudar a poner seguro la manera de encriptar y ofrecerme un ejemplo?
Gracias.

Comment: Lo quieres usar para "encriptar" un password?

Comment: @Pipe, necesito encriptar y desencriptar unos datos de un textarea

Comment: Te puede servir este link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string/

Comment: @Pipe muchas gracias. Utlizaré esta sugerencia que me has dado. ¿En la base de datos el campo donde se guarde la información será un Varchar o VarBinary?

Comment: `varchar`... porque la encriptación devuelve una cadena de caracteres

Comment: ¡Mil gracias @Pipe!

Comment: Todo bien, con gusto